# What do the coins below a game mean?

Tags: atari-50-anniversary-celebration

In the Atari Game Library, each game has 1, 2 or 4 coins below them. The coins are black and red with a white "i" on them. What do these coins mean?

[image: Missile Command with two coins belwo it]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those look like "people" icons, likely denoting the number of players a game supports (1, 2, and 4 players).

I couldn't find a source stating so, but [Missile Command](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missile_Command) supported up to two players, so I would think that is what those icons are.

Comment: Other games lineup with coins meaning number of players.. Lunar Lander (1), Missile Command (2), Pong (2), 3-D Tic-Tac-Toe (2), Warlords (4), etc.